# controller_manager spawner dies after spawning

Tags: ros, controller-manager, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was working fine  for loading controller for Gazebo and then after doing sudo apt-get upgrade (that I think installed some extra gazebo stuff), it started crashing. (disk34_tran is the last controller in my list, so all controllers are loaded correctly)

```
[/maru/maru_controller INFO 4.373000]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: joint_state_controller, clamp_tran, belt1_tran, belt2_tran, z_tran, yaw_tran, height_tran, rad_tran, pusher_tran, drive_tran, fixed_drive_tran, eject_drive_tran, disk0_tran, disk1_tran, disk2_tran, disk3_tran, disk4_tran, disk5_tran, disk6_tran, disk7_tran, disk8_tran, disk9_tran, disk10_tran, disk11_tran, disk12_tran, disk13_tran, disk14_tran, disk15_tran, disk16_tran, disk18_tran, disk19_tran, disk20_tran, disk21_tran, disk22_tran, disk23_tran, disk24_tran, disk25_tran, disk26_tran, disk27_tran, disk28_tran, disk29_tran, disk30_tran, disk31_tran, disk32_tran, disk33_tran, disk17_tran, disk34_tran
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 212, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 204, in main
    resp = switch_controller(loaded, [], 2)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 435, in __call__
Segmentation fault
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 4012, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/mehdi/.ros/log/40838168-0520-11e5-9545-48d2245dedaf/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/mehdi/.ros/log/40838168-0520-11e5-9545-48d2245dedaf/gazebo-2*.log
    return self.call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 525, in call
    raise ServiceException("transport error completing service call: %s"%(str(e)))
rospy.service.ServiceException: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
[/maru/maru_controller INFO 4.374000]: Shutting down spawner. Stopping and unloading controllers...
[/maru/maru_controller WARN 4.374000]: Controller Spawner couldn't reach controller_manager to take down controllers. Waited for 30 second(s).
```

What could be the reason for this crash and how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210071/controller_manager-spawner-dies-after-spawning/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're providing little information about your setup. But from the `rospy.service.ServiceException` and the segmentation fault, I'd say that you might have an inconsistent set of binaries installed.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-05-28**:
I deleted and reinstalled Gazebo4 but then noticed that there was a package conflict so I deleted Gazebo4 again in installed Gazebo2 and its ROS packages. It works now.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-05-28**:
Yeah, `gazebo_ros_control` binaries are released against Gazebo2, that explains the crash. Glad it's answered.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-06-25**:
I'm actually having an identical issue. Using Gazebo 5 with hector_quadrotor_gazebo and ros-indigo-gazebo5 packages. All hector packages built from source to build against Gazebo 5. Was working for months, did an apt-get upgrade, rebuilt, and now I get a very similar error.

**Comment by [Bill Warner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22938/bill-warner/) on 2015-06-25**:
This would seem to indicate that some portion of ros-indigo-gazebo5-pkgs is not functional.

**Comment by [danacity](https://answers.ros.org/users/19622/danacity/) on 2016-07-11**:
i got the same problem in Gazebo7 with ROS Indigo. How to get out of this problem? So frustrated with this error.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-07-12**:
@bilynbk the fastest and easiest way would be to use gazebo 2, the one recommended for ROS Indigo, or move to ROS Kinetic which comes with a newer Gazebo version

**Comment by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on 2017-03-15**:
@bilynbk did you finally fix this issue?